# Do I need to import do an import in Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase cloud functions. Do I need to add an import tag when using something like Math.floor()?

Comment: take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web-version-9_2

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Firebase *functions* are written as "any other" JavaScript Node.js code. That includes imports.
[`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) is a *global* JavaScript object. There isn't any need to import it.

I think you need mostly look into the documentation [how to start](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstarts). And play with it yourself.